# Django forms min and max price inputs

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a form that shows 2 different textboxes with a minimum and a maximum value of my model's price field, which is a DecimalField. But I'm not sure where to begin. I know I can calculate the min and max value, but I'm not sure how to add that to the placeholder and/or value text. So for right now, I'm just using the view to push the values, but they won't submit in the form. Here is my code so far:

**forms.py**

```
class ProductSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
price_min = forms.DecimalField()
price_max = forms.DecimalField()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['length_range'].empty_label = "any size"
    self.fields['hull_type'].empty_label = "any type"
    self.fields['power'].empty_label = "any type"
    self.fields['speed'].empty_label = "any speed"
    self.fields['hull_only_available'].empty_label = None
    self.fields['price_min'].widget.attrs['min'] = kwargs['price']['price__min']
    self.fields['price_max'].widget.attrs['max'] = kwargs['price']['price__max']

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('length_range', 'hull_type', 'price', 'power', 'speed', 'hull_only_available')
```

**views.py**

```
class IndexView(FormView):
template_name = 'index.html'
form_class = ProductSearchForm
success_url = "search/"

def get_price(self):
    price = getattr(self, "_price", None)
    if price is None:
        price = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))
        setattr(self, "_price", price)
    return price

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['length_ranges'] = LengthRange.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    context['hull_types'] = Hull.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    context['power_configs'] = PowerConfiguration.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    context['speed_ranges'] = SpeedRange.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    return context

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form_kwargs = super(IndexView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    form_kwargs['price'] = self.get_price()
    return form_kwargs
```

**index.html**

```
<form class="nl-form" action="{% url 'boatsales:search' %}" method="get">
                                A boat with a length of
                                {{ form.length_range }}
                                , with hull type of
                                {{ form.hull_type }}
                                with
                                {{ form.power }}
                                power
                                configuration and a top speed between
                                {{ form.speed }}.
                                My budget is from $<input type="text" value="{{ price.price__min|intcomma }}"
                                                         placeholder="{{ price.price__min|intcomma }}"
                                                         data-subline="Our current lowest price is: <em>{{ price__min|intcomma }}</em>"/>
                                to
                                $<input
                                        type="text" value="{{ price.price__max|intcomma }}"
                                        placeholder="{{ price.price__min|intcomma }}"
                                        data-subline="Our current highest price is: <em>{{ price.price__min|intcomma }}</em>"/>.
                                Hull only
                                availability <select>
                                <option value="False" selected>is not</option>
                                <option value="True">is</option>
                            </select> a concern.
                                <div class="container">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                            class="btn-a btn-a_size_large btn-a_color_theme">
                                        Show me the results!
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**EDIT**
Now I'm getting a TypeError: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'price'`

Seems to be coming from this line in views.py

```
context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, ignore my previous answer, I completely misunderstood your question.

I think the problem here is that you are creating a form with only the fields that are contained in `Product`.

However you need a form that contains MORE fields. There is nothing that limits you to only using fields that are in the model.

So the idea would be to ignore `price` (which is a specific price), and instead add `price_min` and `price_max`:

```
class ProductSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price_min = form.DecimalField()
    price_max = form.DecimalField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pop the price argument, as the parent form doesn't know about it!
        price = kwargs.pop("price")
        super(ProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ... existing code...
        self.fields['price_min'].widget.attrs['min'] = price['price__min']
        self.fields['price_min'].widget.attrs['max'] = price['price__max']
        self.fields['price_max'].widget.attrs['min'] = price['price__min']
        self.fields['price_max'].widget.attrs['max'] = price['price__max']
```

You can use these fields in your template as any other regular field.

You can then pass the current price values as you kind of already attempting to do, via `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    # ... existing code...
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super(IndexView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['price'] = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))
        return form_kwargs
```

Extra suggestion:

If you want to avoid making a query to `Product` twice to get the min/max, then you can create a method that caches the result, like:

(in view)

```
    def get_price(self):
        price = getattr(self, "_price", None)
        if price is None:
            price = Product.objects.all().aggregate(Min('price'), Max('price'))
            setattr(self, "_price", price)
        return price
```

and then you can call `self.get_price()` to populate the form kwargs and the template context.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I'm still missing something. I updated the forms.py and views.py code in my post so you can see. I'm getting a TypeError now.

Comment: Hey Justin. Sorry it's not easy to test the code, so my solution is approximate.

You got that error because the parent form doesn't know about `price`, so we need to "pop" it out of the `kwargs` before they are passed to `super()`. See my updated solution :)

Comment: I totally get it. No worries, man. And this worked btw. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm getting an integer in my UpdateView that I wanna add to the model forms **IntegerField** as max number, but how can I do that?